# How to create a terminal in python which can run other python programs

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, pipe

I want to create a terminal in python which can run another python program. I don't need to run terminal commands in that terminal, I only need to run a python file or (string of multi-line python code which request inputs from the user) and send inputs from that terminal to that program and get outputs & error messages.

As a example let's get my other python program in a file named code.py

```
#code.py file
in1=input("in1: ")
in2=input("in2: ")
print("You entered",in1,in2)
```

I want to run that code.py file from my terminal. It should display `in1:`  and wait for the user input and then get the input from user and then display `in2:`  and wait for the input. After that print the output of that code. Finally I want to create a simple terminal which can run another python file as in windows CMD. No need to accept several terminal commands.

And also I want to know, is there any way to do that same thing(Including waiting for the user input also) using a string which contains code in that above code.py file instead of using a file. like below,

```
code='in1=input("in1: ")\nin2=input("in2: ")\nprint("You entered",in1,in2)'
```

Please note that this is such a example, content of code.py file/code string is not static.

Comment: Requirement is not 100% clear.
Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @Pitto thank you. I have updated my question now. I think it is clear now.